# Ink filepicker doesn't work with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, filepicker.io

When you click on a page that has the filepicker button in a Rails app, the button doesn't render. I assume it's because it triggers on window load only. Turbolinks requires a callback for page:load.

How to fix/solve?

Answer (score 0):

The solution now is to move

```
<%= filepicker_js_include_tag %>
```

from inside the `<head>` tag to inside `<body>` tag.

See this discussion: https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails/issues/52